# Prevent users from adding more users in Skype's group chat

Tags: skype, chat

I'm a creator of a Skype chat group and I have never left this group, nevertheless I can't demote anyone to "User" to prevent them from adding more users to the group. I can promote them to "Master", it works, then I demote back to "User" and /showmembers shows me that this user has role "SPEAKER" and he can still add new members.

How do I prevent users from adding more people to Skype's group chat?

Skype version: 6.16.0.105

Answer (score -1):

You can stop specific people from joining your group by adding them to a ban list. Don’t worry, you can always change your mind later!

To remove someone who has already joined the group and ban them at the same time simply type /kickban [SkypeName]

To ban someone who is not in the group from joining type /set banlist +[SkypeName]

To remove the ban on someone just type /set banlist –[SkypeName]